# Small number of entities vs Large number of entities - How many objects is this?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I'm currently designing a partition strategy for my application which uses Azure Table Storage.

There's a great guide from the docs [Real World: Designing a Scalable Partitioning Strategy for Windows Azure Table Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh508997.aspx) which talks about Partition Sizing.

In the pros vs cons table it compares `Small number of entities` and `Large number of entities`.

But how many objects is really considered being a "Large number" and a "Small number"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at an old (out of date) article.  Partitioning for Azure Storage has changed, because of the new scalability enhancements since June 2012, Microsoft is using SSDs/new architecture for storage.

Look at this article, it doesn't answer your question about what is a "small number", but it does give you on what your "scaling targets" should be.  What does that mean? It means that Microsoft Azure Storage should scale to these targets, but you have to tweak your design:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/11/02/windows-azure-s-flat-network-storage-and-2012-scalability-targets.aspx

For example, a single partition (on the new Azure Storage) can scale up to 2,000 entities/second.  Your partitioning strategy depends on your queries and what throughput do you need.